# Getting error "It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient"

Tags: selenium, appium, winappdriver

I am not able to launch the Notepad.exe via windows application driver with selenium and Appium

Below are the versions of all

```
**Appium** : 1.15.1
**Selenium Standalone** : 3.141.59
**Java Client** : 7.2.0
```

I am starting Windows application driver server like this `WinAppDriver.exe 4727`.

I have tried this using testng and junit both,but getting the same error again and again.

**Error Message is below** :

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: It is impossible to create a
>   new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient,
>   InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible Build info:
>   version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time:
>   '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z' System info: host: 'DESKTOP-0TL6S7C', ip:
>   '172.18.2.139', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_221' Driver info: driver.version:
>   WindowsDriver

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned in the question about using *Selenium Standalone v3.141.59* but as per the error trace logs:

> Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'

Which is almost 2 years old.

Upgrading your build with **Selenium Standalone v3.141.59** will solve the issue.

Comment: Actually I am using POM.XML and in that I have specified latest version of selenium standalone V 3.141.59,but when I am running my code its not getting the latest one and throwing error in which it includes V 3.12.0.

Now I tried without POM.XML and added all jars manually to my project folder and its working fine for me now :)...Thanks for replying